# Save POST Data To Page Indefinitely

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

**Is there a way to save `form` data using the `post` method to a page indefinitely?** For instance, I input some fields into a `form`(form1) and that posts to "page.php" and this page displays that data even after a page refresh, basically forever, until I update that data with new inputted data from that same `form`(form1).

While typing this question I thought about one possible method: save the data to a database and call it from "page.php". I will probably end up doing that if I can't do it with `post` alone.

**If it can't be done by `post` alone, how would I be able to update "page.php" with new data from the database?** For example, I input some fields, we'll call it "data1", into the database and "page.php" calls it and displays it. Then I input new fields, "data2", into the database. How can I tell the page to ONLY display "data2" instead of "data1"? Basically, it should always display the newest or most current data on the database.

**What other solutions are there to accomplish this?**

Comment: You need permanent storage

Comment: sorry guys computer is having a moment :) lets try it again. You need permenant storage, file or db. if you don't care who has access to the data go with a local file, faster, dont need sql just php

Comment: how can i save it to a file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to display the data "indefinitely" you gonna have to store it one way or another. It can be either a file or a database.
In the case you described you might do a database "update" to only store recent values OR select the newest record from your database.
If you have a auto increment database column (id) this should get you the newest record:

```
SELECT * FROM yourtable ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

Which means: Sort 'yourtable' rows by id values, highest first, take the first one, return all column values for that row.
This way every time you query this you'll get the record with the highest id value - meaning the one that was last inserted.

Storing in a file is also a possible scenario. It depends on the situation. You can either store raw data (for example a JSON of your $_POST array) and use it dynamically later or even store the whole output you simply gonna include to your script (with html tags and everything else you need).

Comment: How would I be able to store in a file?

Comment: Edited my answer slightly. Basically if all that info is shown in a block you can store the output you then "include" in your script. If you need the data "all over your page" you can consider storing JSON string or some other reversible "array to string" solution. After all you only need data from a single form post so using a file might be a wise choice.

Comment: could you show me an example of how I would convert the post data to JSON? I am not familiar with JSON.

Comment: you use json_encode function to encode your $_POST array to string and store it. Then you use json_decode function to convert the string you read back to array. It's really simple, look at the examples in http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php or http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php. An example would be: $str = json_encode($_POST); and then when you need the data again $post = json_decode($str);

Comment: Would I use that with `file_put_contents` to write it into a file? Could u give me a solid example? I want to see the process of the `form` data being sent to the php file and then encoded into json and written into the file. Been doing some reading on json and I still can't seem to grasp its use. It's also because a lot of people use json with js, jquery and other languages and I just want to use php.

Comment: Well that's the very basics of PHP :) Basically by calling file_put_contents('your path and filename', json_encode($_POST)); you write the data to the file. And by calling $theData = json_decode(file_get_contents(your path and filename)); you restore old post data to you $theData variable. I suggest at least reading about every function you're not familiar yet.